# Problem with input and output dimensions when implementing ConvNN

Tags: python-3.x, conv-neural-network

When trying to implement a CNN I get the following error: ValueError: A target array with shape (3131, 272, 47) was passed for an output of shape (None, 269, 47) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

I am just learning about Neural Networks and I thought I was understanding how to implement simple CNNs however when I try to implement on a more complex task I am finding I am not able to fix this error: ValueError: A target array with shape (3131, 128, 47) was passed for an output of shape (None, 125, 47) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

This is what I am trying to implement:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Embedding(input_dim=length_word_index, output_dim=length_tag_index, input_length=MAX_LENGTH))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=MAX_LENGTH, kernel_size=4, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(length_tag_index))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    print(model.summary())  

 Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 271, 47)           535283    
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 268, 271)          51219     
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 268, 47)           12784     
_________________________________________________________________
activation (Activation)      (None, 268, 47)           0         
=================================================================

y_train shape:  (3131, 272)
MAX_LENGTH:  272
length_word_index:  11389 
num_labels:  47
```

I understand it is likely difficult to troubleshoot this without more information however all I would like to know is where to start troubleshooting. When looking at the problem, input is (3131, 128, 47) meaning (length of y_train, MAX_LENGTH, num_labels) it seems that the second parameter being 128 (the MAX_LENGTH) is changed to an output shape of 125 which is causing the problem. I just have no idea why the parameter is changing from 128 to 125.

It is not a problem with the training or test data as I have also implemented an LSTM with the same data which works no problem:

```
model = Sequential()
    model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=(MAX_LENGTH, )))
    model.add(Embedding(length_word_index, 128))
    model.add(Conv1D(filters=MAX_LENGTH, kernel_size=4, padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)))
    model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(length_tag_index)))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))

    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(0.001), metrics=['accuracy']))
    model.summary()
```

Comment: Your *Conv1D* layer probably needs *padding="same"*.

Comment: @Kalpit thank you! That was the problem!